# first column data is missing in while loop when mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, fetch

i have a problem with while loop.In this first column data is not getting remaining data is getting 
here is my code

```
$result_By_Vendor_And_Title = mysql_query("select * from cek6q_jshopping_products where vendor_id = " . $vendor . " and name_en-GB='" . $title . "'");

if (mysql_fetch_array($result_By_Vendor_And_Title)) {
      echo 'found';
      while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_By_Vendor_And_Title) ) {
          echo $id = $rows['product_id'];
      }
}
echo 'not found';
```

Here i want to display all the ids but i have getting all the ids except first one how i can get first one.

Comment: Because the mysql_fetch_array() call that you do to test for `found` is fetching and discarding the first row, Use [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to identify if a result has been found.... then learn about MySQLi/PDO and prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: Thanks Your code is not working, i have not getting first row till now also

Comment: We've explained the cause problem to you: you have two coded solutions below, both of which will work... if they're not working, then you've messed something else up.... show us your latest code

Answer (score 1):

Because the `fetch_array` you do to test for found is fetching and discarding the first row
just try this

```
$result_By_Vendor_And_Title = mysql_query("select * from cek6q_jshopping_products where vendor_id = '" . $vendor . "' and name_en-GB='" . $title . "'");

if($result_By_Vendor_And_Title){
if(mysql_num_rows($result_By_Vendor_And_Title)>0){
   echo 'found';
   while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_By_Vendor_And_Title) ) { 
     echo $id = $rows['product_id'];
   }
}else{ 
    echo 'not found';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Your code is not working, i have not getting first row till now also

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if( mysql_num_rows( $result_By_Vendor_And_Title ) > 0 ) {
    echo 'found';
    while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_By_Vendor_And_Title) )
    { echo $id = $rows['product_id']; } 
}else{
    echo 'not found';   
}
```

**Dont** use mysql_* functions.

Comment: Why not to use mysql_ can u elaborate me plz

Comment: Because its not secure and deprecated now. Learn MySQLi/PDO. There are numerous tutorials on web. Did it solved your query?

Comment: The `mysql_*` library is **deprecated** as of `PHP 5.5.0`. So if you are upgrading your PHP in future, this application wont work.

Comment: Thanks Your code is not working, i have not getting first row till now also